# How to use the specific hypothesis apply in to the model in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Now, I use the pipeline in ML. The learning algorithm is the logistic regression. Then, I get coefficients (weights) and intercept from the logistic model, which means I have a hypothesis.

In general, I can use transform function to predict the testing data in the pipeline model. However, I design a new method to improve the hypothesis. Therefore, I get a modified hypothesis (coefficients (weights) and intercept).

```
//fitting the model
.....
......
val model = pipeline.fit(trainingRDD)
//predict the testing data
val predictionResult = model.transform(testingRDD)

//Now, I want to modify the hypothesis and predict again
//getting the hypothesis
val h = model.stages.collect{
      case lr: LogisticRegressionModel => Vectors.dense(lr.coefficients.toArray :+ lr.intercept)
    }.head

//modify the hypothesis
......
......
val new_h = mothed(h)
//Now, I want to modify the hypothesis and predict again
//What should I do?
```

The question is that:

How can I use the modified hypothesis to predict the training data in spark?

I think a bad way:

The modified hypothesis is run using for-loop in testing data, then I can get the new prediction's result. However, I think it is not effective.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean a new model with your coefficients and intercept? Or do you mean replace how those are computed by your formula?

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto I mean that I have a modified coefficients and intercept, and replace the old one.

Comment: Can you share some code, it is unclear what the issue is.

Comment: @mtoto sorry, I add some code. I hope it will be better.